# Short word or phrase for the acquisition of specific pieces of knowledge

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

On the [Latin Language Stack Exchange](https://latin.stackexchange.com/) (which is in private beta right now), I wish to create a tag for question asking for how we come to know certain facts about the Latin language, for example:

- [How do we know how the Romans pronounced Latin?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/66/49)
- [How do we know that *comperendinare* means *to adjourn for three days?*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/386/49)

I am looking for a concise English name for this tag. It can be a word of any class or a short phrase.

So far I considered and rejected

- *how-do-we-know* – This is what I named the tag for now, but I consider it rather unelegant for a tag name.
- *[epistemology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemology)* – This on a different level as it is about how we acquire knowledge in general, not about how we acquired a specific piece of knowledge.
- *research* – This implies that the knowledge is acquired by a targetted endeavour which does not need to be the case. Also, the word is not well suited for a tag name as it may also apply to research about the Latin language in general.

When answering, please consider whether your suggestion can be interpreted otherwise when used as a tag on a language Stack Exchange (such as this one).

Comment: ***knowledge-acquisition***.

Comment: *How we come to know certain facts about the Latin language* — this sounds most like *methodology*? But it seems the conexion between those two questions is mainly that you know a certain thing about x, but not another thing, and you'd like to know more about the latter. Do you really think people are going to use tags to search for questions like that?

Comment: @DanBron: ...also known as ***question***.

Comment: I like *how-do-we-know* because it's self-explanatory. Somewhat obscure and possibly less accurate alternatives are *proof* or *evidence*.

Comment: [*For the reconstructionist historian, history is defined as the discovery or the '**piecing together**' of the true narrative that is believed to be 'back there'.*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=yKo1PzexFzsC&pg=PA105&lpg=PA105&dq=define+%22piecing+together%22+historical+facts&source=bl&ots=TGn3jnEkJx&sig=XZr0xMZ_bKNxsW6zX8dw3vr-r-Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjAjcmIjqrLAhUDuRoKHYyPAQ0Q6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=define%20%22piecing%20together%22%20historical%20facts&f=false)

Comment: @Cerberus: *Methodology* is something different entirely. It is about how you go on actively acquiring knowledge, not about how you actually acquired some knowledge. It’s somewhat similar to *research* in that respect. (I will answer on the usefulness of that tag in chat.)

Comment: It's difficult for me to see how the two questions are related. I have the context of your question, but as @Cerberus comments, I honestly think I would not have that connection on my own. That's not to say that the "About" page of your site couldn't explain this "How-do-we-know" line of questioning.

Comment: How do we know if Romans wore wigs? How do we know the word for wig in Italian was derived from French? How do we know how it was pronounced in Latin? How do we know...? etc. They may all begin with "How do we know..." but the question themselves are quite different. Tags: 1. History 2. Etymology 3. pronunciation etc.

Comment: All of those questions are asking for the **precedent**. "an earlier event or action that is regarded as an example or guide to be considered in subsequent similar circumstances." –[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=precedent&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps ***evidential-basis*** would work?

Answer (score 2):

You could shorten your first suggestion to: ***how-we-know***.

I like this because it's clear what the tag means and it doesn't use any fancy words.

Answer (score 0):

How about ***philology***?

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philology)

> Philology is the study of language in written historical sources; it is a combination of literary criticism, history, and linguistics.[1] It is more commonly defined as the study of literary texts and written records, the establishment of their authenticity and their original form, and the determination of their meaning.

Comment: Given the context, that would be far too broad. As a tag, it would apply to almost every question on that site.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft- Fine. but I think that's an exaggeration.  I see many questions on the front page of the Area 51 Proposal site that don't seem to be about philology.

Answer (score 0):

***quomodo-scimus***

Oops, you're asking on *English* Language & Usage.

Actually, I think ***how-do-we-know*** is fine. Yes, it's a little inelegant, but it's very clear, it's the first phrase people are likely to think of when seeing if there's a tag for that concept, and it's actually packed with meaning. In English, "how do we know?" carries at least a grain of skepticism: maybe we don't know. This makes the tag intriguing: by reading questions with this tag, you know you're diving into scholarly doubts and controversies.

I think the piercing clarity and plainness of ***how-do-we-know*** actually make it elegant in its own inelegant way.